# Refactoring componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to refactor componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method as it is deprecated. getDerivedStateFromProps will not work because there are references to `this`.

```
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if (this.state.displayErrors) {
       this._validate(nextProps);
     }
   }
```

I refactored it to this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { displayErrors } = this.state;
    if (displayErrors) {
      this._validate(prevProps, prevState);
    }
  }
```

And this this one:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.email.length > 0 && nextProps.password.length > 0) {
      this.props.setLoginDisabled(false);
    } else {
      this.props.setLoginDisabled(true);
    }
  }
```

I refactored it to this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { setLoginDisabled } = this.props;
    if (email.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
      setLoginDisabled(false);
    } else {
      setLoginDisabled(true);
    }
  }
```

and I have not had an error or anything breaking, but I am not sure this is the best refactor. Can anyone recommend a better refactor?

Comment: There may not be a technically "better" way, but with the way things are going, hooks are the future. Here's a section of the docs explaining how to handle this sort of thing https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The refactor looks promising, even react recommends using `componentDidUpdate` over `componentWillReceiveProps`. Although, I would recommend you to harness the full power of the lifecycle methods.

For example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { 
    if(this.props.someprop.value !== prevProps.someprop.value) {
          //do your stuff here.
          //a setState call maybe
    }

  }
```

**What exactly is happening here?**

Comparing previous props with the newly arrived ones before making a state change ensures that your component won't perform any unnecessary re-renders thus helping with the performance.

Also, you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` or `React.PureComponent`.

`shouldComponentUpdate` is useful when you explicitly need to decide if your component should re-render with more checks than `React.PureComponent`.

Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate